# Globally disabling protocols in OpenSSL

Tags: ssl, openssl, gsoap

Is it possible to globally disable TLS 1.1 for an application that is indirectly using OpenSSL?

I would like to disable TLS 1.1 for a C application that makes soap HTTPS calls using gSOAP.
Disabling TLS 1.1 fixes a intermittent SSL connection problem I have been experiencing for the last few days (SSL routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:wrong version number).

Currently TLS 1.1 is disabled by using a custom build of gSOAP but ideally I would like to disable the protocol using a config file or some code in my application.

Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS

OpenSSL 1.0.1-4ubuntu5.20

gSOAP 2.8.4-2

Comment: did you ever find out if it's possible to disable TLSv1 globally for OpenSSL ? It seems like no?

Answer (score 1):

Although there is a global OpenSSL config file it can not be used to restrict the default SSL version(s). And unfortunately there seems to be no API or configuration for the gSOAP library to restrict the SSL version. So you must probably live with your custom build version and hope that someday they provide an API to set the SSL version.

Answer (score 0):

At a minimum you will need gSOAP 2.8.28. Use the `SOAP_TLSv1_2` option with `soap_ssl_client_context()` and `soap_ssl_server_context()` to restrict the TLS protocol to TLSv1.2 only. TLS1.0/TLS1.1/SSLv3 are disabled. You can't combine the SSL/TLS protocol options, so only TLSv1.2 will be enabled with this option. This works with OpenSSL 1.0.1 or later and recent GNUTLS versions. Perhaps there will be new options in upcoming gSOAP releases to support subsets of protocols, which would be nice.